# Derivative definition with double limit

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

The following is an exercise from *Calculus* by Spivak.

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at some point $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that 
>   $$f'(x)=\lim_{h,k\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-k)}{h+k}$$

**My attempt** - I tried something with substitutions, but it doesn't feel rigorous enough:

Let $a=x+h$, and $b=x-k$. 
Then we have 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h,k\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-k)}{h+k} & =\lim_{k\to 0^+}\Bigg[\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-k)}{h+k}\Bigg]
\\ & = \lim_{b\to x^-}\Bigg[\lim_{a\to b}\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}\Bigg]
\\ & = \lim_{b\to x^-}f'(b)
\\ & = f'(x)
\end{align*}

This just feels quite off, but I wasn't sure how else to approach it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your first step is incorrect. There are functions $f(x,y)$ which are *separately* continuous in $x$ and $y$, but not *jointly* continuous in $(x,y)$. Also your next step is wrong: you have $a\to x^+$.

Comment: Try reasoning with $f(y)-f(x)-f'(x)(y-x)=o(|y-x|)$; it might be simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-k)}{h+k} &= \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)+f(x)-f(x-k)}{h+k} \\
&= \frac{f'(x)h+f'(x)k+o(h)+o(k)}{h+k} \xrightarrow[\substack{h\to0^+\\h\to0^+}]{} f'(x) .
\end{split}
$$

Comment: I'm not well versed in asymptotic notation, and I'm not too sure how you get to that last step.

Comment: $o(h)$ is just any function $f(h)$ with the property that $\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{|f(h)|}{h}=0$. But then also $\lim_{\substack{h\to0^+\\k\to0^+}} \frac{|f(h)|}{h+k} \leq \lim_{\substack{h\to0^+\\k\to0^+}} \frac{|f(h)|}{h} = 0$.